# vbscript -- on error resume with a "permission denied"

Tags: windows, vbscript, directory

I have a script that scans subdirectories recursively and deletes files older than X date.  Because permissions are incorrectly set on some folders, I've had to insert an "On Error Resume" into the code as well, where the error occurs.

However, the problem occurs when I do an if statement...

```
if (Err.Number > 0)
{
  MsgBox("Permission denied on....")
}
```

It seems that despite the fact that the script throws an error when it can't delete a file or get a folder's contents, Err.Number isn't increasing.  Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: surely you mean `if err.Number > 0 then: MsgBox "Permission denied on...": end if`? What you've got there looks more like JScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely due to this comparison `Err.Number > 0`.  The assumption here is that error numbers are postive numbers.  However this is actually rarely true.  You should be using `Err.Number <> 0`.

Comment: Apparently this wasn't the issue, but this helped.  I left the "On Error Resume Next" where it was, then moved the If test to another point in the code and it seems to work correctly now.  Thanks!